# How to usw TouchXML to parse opengis xls?

Tags: iphone, touchxml, opengis

I'd like to parse a osm generated xml file. It has got the structure of opengis xls.
I really don't know how to parse that with TouchXML. Hope you guys can help me on that…
Here's some sample xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xls:XLS xmlns:xls="http://www.opengis.net/xls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/xls http://schemas.opengis.net/ols/1.1.0/RouteService.xsd">
  <xls:ResponseHeader xsi:type="xls:ResponseHeaderType"/>
  <xls:Response xsi:type="xls:ResponseType" requestID="123456789" version="1.1" numberOfResponses="1">
    <xls:DetermineRouteResponse xsi:type="xls:DetermineRouteResponseType">
      <xls:RouteSummary>
        <xls:TotalTime>PT4M16S</xls:TotalTime>
        <xls:TotalDistance uom="KM" value="3.5"/>
        <xls:BoundingBox srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:pos>7.0265595 50.7202776</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0430713 50.7270132</gml:pos>
        </xls:BoundingBox>
      </xls:RouteSummary>
      <xls:RouteGeometry>
        <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:pos>7.040837 50.723612</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.040840269701068 50.723621917924525</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0408837 50.7236076</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0405096 50.7232419</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0403821 50.7231206</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0403179 50.7230401</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0402018 50.7228842</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0401206 50.7227684</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0398895 50.7224384</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0396993 50.722163</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0395933 50.7220102</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>7.0393839 50.721871</gml:pos>
```